# $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \left( \frac{E[ Z^n ]}{n!} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}<\infty$ if $Z$ has pdf of the form $c e^{-x}f_X(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $f_X$ be a pdf of a non-negative random variable $X$. Now, let $g_Z(x)=c e^{-x}f_X(x),x \ge 0$ be a new pdf where $c$ the normalization constant.  Let's say that $g_Z$ is pdf of a random variable $Z\ge0$.

My question: Can we show that
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \left(  \frac{E[ Z^n ]}{n!}  \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}<\infty ? 
\end{align}

My intuition: The object is finite if the tail of $g_Z$ decays fast enough.
In this case, the tail decays at the rate of at least $e^{-x}$.

I was thinking of proof along the following lines: choose $A$ large enough such that  $g_Z(x)=c e^{-x}f_X(x)  \le e^{-x}$
\begin{align}
E[ Z^n ]&= \int_0^A z^n  c e^{-z}f_X(z) {\rm d}z+ \int_A^\infty z^n  c e^{-z}f_X(z) {\rm d}z\\
&\le A^n  + \int_A^\infty z^n  e^{-z} {\rm d}z\\
&\le A^n  + n!
\end{align}
where in the last step we used that   $\int_A^\infty z^n  e^{-z} {\rm d}z \le  \int_0^\infty z^n  e^{-z} {\rm d}z=n!$.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \left(  \frac{E[ Z^n ]}{n!}  \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}  \le  \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left(  \frac{A^n +n!}{n!} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le   \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{A^n }{n!} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} =1.  
\end{align}

I am, however, somewhat unsure about this proof. Am I missing something here.

Comment: The catch with your argument is that such an $A$ need not exist - $f$ can have infinitely many very tall (and narrow) spikes. Hint for question: what is $\mathbb{E}[e^Z]$?